# DSL Job in Jenkins and Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to fetch the forks of a certain repo in Github, the same of executing:

`curl -k -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/rackt/redux/forks`

But in a DSL script in Jenkins.

Why? Because I would like to clone all people's fork and build the project on separate jobs generated by [job-dsl-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/).

Of course this is just an example with a repo I found. I'm trying to do it with SSH credentials with private repos.

Do you know which would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved by doing [this (see the Gist I published)](https://gist.github.com/davidpelayo/de4181e93584df7443c9):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def owner = "<owner>"
def project = "<project>"

// curl -k -u <user>:<token> -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/forks > forks.txt

def fetch(addr, params = [:]) {
  def auth = "<personalAPIToken>" // see https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens
  def json = new JsonSlurper()
  return json.parse(addr.toURL().newReader(requestProperties: ["Authorization": "token ${auth}".toString(), "Accept": "application/json"]))
}

def forks = fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${project}/forks")

forks.each {
    def fork = it.full_name
    def name = it.owner.login
    def jobName = "${project}-${name}".replaceAll('/','-')
    job(jobName) {
        scm {
            git {
              remote {
                github(fork, 'https')
                credentials('<idCredentials>')
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a real world example in the [wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki) which details how to create [jobs for branches](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Real-World-Examples#rest-api-calls)

```
def project = 'Netflix/asgard'
def branchApi = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/${project}/branches")
def branches = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())
branches.each {
    def branchName = it.name
    def jobName = "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
    job(jobName) {
        scm {
            git("https://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
        }
    }
}
```

What you will need to do is move the `job` section outside the `each` closure and use the fork name.

As for your comments about ssh and private repos. Its a good idea to keep your ssh key out of the script by using the [Credentials plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) like the [wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Handling-Credentials#the-credentials-plugin) says

> The first option involves the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) which manages
>   credentials in a secure manner and allows Job DSL scripts to reference
>   credentials by their identifier. It is also the most secure option
>   because the credentials do not need to passed to the Job DSL script.

```
// use the github-ci-key credentials for authentication with GitHub
job('example-1') {
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                github('account/repo', 'ssh')
                credentials('github-ci-key')
            }
        }
    }
}
```